# What is the difference below?

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to find out what is the difference between the code line below in terms of Keys.

```
 Entity e = new Entity("Employee", 100);
```

And

```
 Key k = KeyFactory.createKey("Employee", 100);
 Entity e = new Entity("Employee", k);
```

Answer (score 3):

## Short version

The first line creates an `Employee` entity of id `100` whereas the second one creates an `Employee` entity that is **a child** of the entity created in the first line.

## More details

```
Entity e = new Entity("Employee", 100);
```

This line creates a new entity of kind `Employee` and with an id of `100`.

```
Key k = KeyFactory.createKey("Employee", 100);
Entity e = new Entity("Employee", k);
```

Those lines do the following :

1. Create a key referencing the entity of kind `Employee` and the id `100`. This key could be used to reference the entity created by the first line of code you shared.
2. Create an entity of type `Employee` **who has for ancestor** the entity referenced by the key created before. The new entity also has an id, but since you did not specify it in the constructor, it will be a `long` generated by App Engine when the entity is saved into the datastore.

If you're unsure about the concept of ancestors, checkout out [this documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Ancestor_paths).

Comment: Additionally, the constructor `Entity(Key key)` is would be the same as `new Entity("Employee", 100);`